# $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded analog of row operations for supermatrices

Tags: supersymmetry, super-algebra, super-linear-algebra

I'm working on some research involving supermatrices, and I was wondering if there was a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded analog of row operations for supermatrices.

It seems to me that it makes sense to have row operations among the first $p$ even rows and the last $q$ odd rows in a $(p\mid q)\times (r\mid s)$ supermatrix, however a row operation from an even row to an odd row is either undefined or requires a trick of some sort (possibly a parity transpose)?

Any help would be appreciated, references to literature would be excellent.